# FloatField vs DecimalField in Django and JS/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

I have a Django app as the backend a React app as the frontend. Most of my Django fields related to prices/monetary values were `FloatField`. It worked with the frontend: when receiving objects from the backend I could see that those fields were `number`s and I could make calculations with them. But I've recently changed from `FloatField` to `DecimalField`, and now on the frontend the prices are assumed as `string`.
Why is that happening and what is the best approach to deal with this? Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49770815/8770336

Comment: @EneP Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DecimalField` also takes an optional argument, `coerce_to_string`. If set to `True` the representation will be output as a string. If set to `False` the representation will be left as a Decimal instance and the final representation will be determined by the renderer.

If unset, this will default to the same value as the `COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING` setting, which is `True` unless set otherwise.

As you can see the default value of `COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING` is True, if you want to change it you can do this:

```
# settings.py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING': False,
    ... 
}
```